# How to display a button only when the width of a div exceeds certain height javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to show button only when the height of a div exceeds certain height. on clicking this button it should show the full content of the div.

What i am trying to do?

I have a side panel which contains list items (which is a div containing svg, span and time elements) now when the height of this div exceeds max-height (49px) it should should display a button and on clicking this button should show the full content of div...

What i have tried so far?
I have set the max-height for the div inside list item to 49px and overflow to hidden.

I have added a button for each list item with id "show_button" whose display is set to none initially. andi check for the height of div exceeding the max-limit using code below.

```
if (document.getElementsByClassName('div_list').offsetHeight < 
    document.getElementsByClassName('div_list').scrollHeight) {
        document.getElementById('show_button').style.display = 'inline';}
}
```

But this is not working...when i log the offsetheight and scrollheight of div_list i get undefined.

Below is the code,

```
<li>
   <div className="div_list">
       <div className="details">
           <Svg/>
           <span>some text exceeding div height some text exceeding div 
               height some text exceeding div height some text exceeding div 
               height some text exceeding div height
           </span>
       </div>
       <time>{time_var}</time>
   </div>
   <button id="show_button" onClick={this.handle_show_btn}><SvgAccUp/> 
   </button>
```

```
handle_show_btn = () => {
    document.getElementsByClassName('div_list').style.overflow = 'visible';
};

render = () => {
    if (document.getElementsByClassName('div_list').offsetHeight < 
        document.getElementsByClassName('div_list').scrollHeight) {
            document.getElementById('show_button').style.display = 'inline';
    }}
```

css code,

```
.div_list {
    max-height: 49px;
    overflow: hidden;
 }

 #show_button {
     display: none;
 }
```

There will be multiple list items with div classsname div_list and if anyof those height exceeds 49px button should be shown. Could someone let me know how to fix it. Thanks.

Comment: Question title says "width", question says "height".  In either case you can use [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like structure.  It's not going to have the properties you're looking for, but individual elements within it might.  Try either selecting another way, or using the first element in the array, or whatever suits your need here.

Answer (score 0):

In your script, try:
document.querySelector(“.div_list”)

In your html, try:
div class=“div_list”

Assuming this the only element with this class. Otherwise set an id and reference it in your script as “#div_list”

Answer (score 0):

But, you are working in react, why use the js/jQuery approach? React gives you simpler way to get this.

See a small [example I made](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-366zgu). The core of the solution is the simple `Expandable` component:

```
const Expandable = ({baseHeight, children, style}) => {
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);
  const [overflow, setOverflow] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div style={{...style, position: 'relative', overflow: 'hidden', height: (expanded ? null : baseHeight)}}
        ref={v => v && setOverflow(v.offsetHeight < v.scrollHeight)}
    >
      {children}
      {overflow && <button onClick={() => setExpanded(true)} style={{position: 'absolute', bottom: 0}}>expand</button>}
    </div>
  );
};
```

What you do is you put your content inside a container and using the `ref` function checks if it has overflow or not. If it does, you add an expand button.

I kept it simple and did the style inline to avoid complexity. Obviously, this can be taken further, the principle is what matters.

Comment: thanks for the answer. within expandable component how can i rewrite onclick method setExpanded true...es6 doesn't accept direct arrow functions?